# Creating custom dynamic JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to achieve the following dynamic JSON string creation. I can produce the `id` part but don't how to produce the `name` part. Ids are from the list and name is from the textbox.

I tried a lot but nothing seems to work. I want to select both strings and text box should result as below.

```js
{
  "name": "GROUP-X1",
  "objects": [{ // this part is needed as a complete string
    "type": "Host",
    "id": "0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589948757"
  }, {
    "type": "Host",
    "id": "0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589945523"
  }]
}
```

```js
var output = createJSON1();

function createJSON1() {
  var arr = $("#select1 > option").map((index, val) => ({
    "type": "Host",
    id: val.value
  })).get();
  return JSON.stringify(arr);
}

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text" id="srch-obj" value="GROUP-X1">
<select id="select1" multiple size="2" style="width: 480px">
  <option>0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589948757</option>
  <option>0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589945523</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already builds the `objects` array. As such, all you need to do is wrap the output within another object providing the `name` property which you can retrieve from the value of `#srch-obj`. Try this:

```js
var output = createJSON1();

function createJSON1() {
  let obj = {
    name: $('#srch-obj').val(),
    objects: $("#select1 > option").map((t, el) => ({
      type: "Host",
      id: el.value
    })).get()
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text" id="srch-obj" value="GROUP-X1">
<select id="select1" multiple size="2" style="width: 480px">
  <option>0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589948757</option>
  <option>0050569A-7800-0ed3-0000-008589945523</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: The `get()` call was in your original code, I simply copied it over. It retrieves the content from within the jQuery object. Normally this is a DOM Element, but as we've used `map()` it's an array. More info in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/get/